# React useEffect hook creating infinite loop of renders in ThreeJS Grafana Panel Plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, three.js, infinite-loop

I am building a Grafana Panel Plugin using ThreeJS. I loaded in a .gltf object and it displays correctly in the Panel with no data. Now I am trying to add the data piece to the project.

The Goal is to have a Panel that reads in Data from the user selected Datasource in the Query tab, and rotates a .gltf object in real time based on streamed roll, pitch, and yaw values (in Radians).

I have a datasource streaming roll, pitch, and yaw data at 30msg/min. I am getting thousands of roll, pitch, and yaw values logged in the console in ONE second.

the most recent data point is accessed with:

```
const latestYaw = series.fields[1].values.get(series.fields[1].values.length - 1);
const latestPitch = series.fields[2].values.get(series.fields[2].values.length - 1);
const latestRoll = series.fields[3].values.get(series.fields[3].values.length - 1);
```

and that data is used here:

```
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  resizeRendererToDisplaySize();

  if (model) {
    if (yaw !== undefined && pitch !== undefined && roll !== undefined) {
      model.rotation.set(
        (pitch * Math.PI) / 180,
        (yaw * Math.PI) / 180,
        (roll * Math.PI) / 180,
        'YXZ'
      );
      console.log('Model rotations:', yaw, pitch, roll)
    }
  } else {
    console.error('Model is undefined.');
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
});`
```

The above code prints this in the console log:

[image]
As you can see above, the code is over producing messages (44k messages in about 10 seconds) and i think its causing the animation loop to crash.
...

SimplePanel.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { PanelProps } from '@grafana/data';
import { SimpleOptions } from 'types'; // Import your types file
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

interface Props extends PanelProps<SimpleOptions> {}

export const SimplePanel: React.FC<Props> = ({ options, data, width, height }) => {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [yaw, setYaw] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);
  const [pitch, setPitch] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);
  const [roll, setRoll] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);
  const [contextLost, setContextLost] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current || contextLost) {
      return;
    }
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    try {
      loader.load('./public/Blackhawk.gltf', (gltf) => {
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
          75,
          window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
          0.1,
          1000
        );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        if (containerRef.current) {
          containerRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        }

        const model = gltf.scene;
        model.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
        scene.add(model);

        // Adjust camera position
        const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(model);
        const size = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
        const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

        const maxDim = Math.max(size.x, size.y, size.z);
        const fov = camera.fov * (Math.PI / 180);
        let distance = maxDim / (2 * Math.tan(fov / 2));
        distance += maxDim * 0.25;

        camera.position.copy(center);
        camera.position.z += distance;
        camera.lookAt(center);

        // Optional: Add lighting to the scene
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        directionalLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);
        scene.add(directionalLight);

        function resizeRendererToDisplaySize() {
          const canvas = renderer.domElement;
          const width = window.innerWidth;
          const height = window.innerHeight;
          const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
          if (needResize) {
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            camera.aspect = width / height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          }
        }

        function animate() {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
          resizeRendererToDisplaySize();

          if (model) {
            if (yaw !== undefined && pitch !== undefined && roll !== undefined) {
              model.rotation.set(
                (pitch * Math.PI) / 180,
                (yaw * Math.PI) / 180,
                (roll * Math.PI) / 180,
                'YXZ'
              );
              // console.log('Model rotations:', yaw, pitch, roll)
            }
          } else {
            console.error('Model is undefined.');
          }
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        animate();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof WebGLRenderingContext) {
        // Handle context lost error, e.g., recreate the context
        console.error('WebGL context lost. You may need to handle context loss.');
        setContextLost(true);
      } else {
        throw error; // Re-throw other errors
      }
    }
  }, [containerRef, width, height, pitch, roll, yaw, contextLost]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Subscribe to data updates and update rotation values
    const series = data.series[0]; // Extract the series object

    if (series) {
      const latestYaw = series.fields[5].values.get(series.fields[5].values.length - 1);
      const latestPitch = series.fields[4].values.get(series.fields[4].values.length - 1);
      const latestRoll = series.fields[3].values.get(series.fields[3].values.length - 1);

      setYaw(latestYaw);
      setPitch(latestPitch);
      setRoll(latestRoll);

      console.log('Latest Roll:', latestRoll);
      console.log('Latest Pitch:', latestPitch);
      console.log('Latest Yaw:', latestYaw);
    }
  }, [data.series]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={containerRef}
      style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', overflow: 'hidden' }}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

Why is the console log producing so many messages?
is my useEffect hooks causing an infinite loop that produces too much data and crashes the animation loop?

Again, the goal is to have a panel that will read streaming roll, pitch, and yaw values coming from a datasource and update the model's rotation real-time.

[image: Panel Editor]